# Inductive proof - Inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, proof-explanation, education

I am trying to do mathematical induction to prove an inequality. However, I got stuck in the middle of the proof. I have started my proof from the inductive step $3^{k+1}=3^k*3 ≥3k*3$. I am stuck in here. The below picture is about what I did. I also tried in a separate way. Picture number $2$ is the alternate way that I tried to prove my equation. The main question is attached to image $1$.
Using mathematical induction, prove:
$〖3n≤3〗^n$ for all natural numbers $n$

Can anyone please help me out with that?
[Here is the snip of the problem(First attempt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDXoh.png)
[Second attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43G77.png)

Comment: "I got stuck in the middle of the proof" Thats not enough information.  Tell us *more* about what you have done and what aspect you are trying to figure out.

Comment: Title says *equation* and body says *inequality*!?

Comment: I have edited a few things in my question. The pictures are about what I have done. And this is my first-time post in Stackexchange. I will really appreciate if you guys help me out. I definitely tried by myself and added it to the picture.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are told to prove by induction, I will proceed by induction on $n$

For the base case we know  for $n=1$, $3^1 = 3$. Thus assume the assertion holds for $n=k$ with $1 \leq k  \leq n$. Consider $n=k+1$,

We have $3^{k+1} = 3^k.3 \geq 3k.3 = 3k+3k+3k >  3k+3 = 3(k+1)$  establishing $n = k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather*}
3^{n}  >3n\\
3^{n} +3 >3( n+1)\\
Now,\ 3^{n+1}  >3^{n} +3,\ \\
because\ 2\times 3^{n}  >3\ for\ all\ n.\\
Hence,\ 3^{n+1}  >3( n+1) ,\ hence\ proved.\\
\\
\end{gather*}